# How to make grub stop appearing every time I boot?

Tags: boot, grub2

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and grub selections appear each time I boot. This happens on both of my computers.

I have tried editing the /etc/defaults/grub to use default, to use the 0 entry, and ran the update on it. But nothing seems to solve the problem.

(showing uncommented lines)

```
$ sudo nano /etc/default/grub 
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

$ sudo update-grub
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-25-generic-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-25-generic-pae
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-24-generic-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-24-generic-pae
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
  No volume groups found
done
```

Answer (score 6):

Grub2 will boot straight into the default operating system if no other operating system is detected. No menu will be displayed. If another operating system is detected, the GRUB 2 menu will display.

But if the grub menu still displays, you may need to change the GRUB_TIMEOUT value from 10 to 0.

**`GRUB_TIMEOUT=10`**

to

**`GRUB_TIMEOUT=0`**

GRUB_TIMEOUT=value is the number of seconds before the default entry is automatically booted.

Answer (score 5):

Open the terminal and run this command:

```
root@penreturns:~$ sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Remove comment  line (add "#"):

```
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
```

It must look like this (by default)

```
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
```

Update your GRUB with this comand:

```
root@penreturns:~$ sudo update-grub
```

Reboot your system and you will see how the system will now stop at the GRUB2 boot screen.

Enjoy!

Comment: So do I add `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT` or remove `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT` ? From your phrasing, I'm not 100% sure.