# How can I get GRUB to appear after installing Ubuntu with Windows 7 using a LiveUSB?

Tags: grub2, bootloader

I booted Ubuntu 12.04 LTS from a LiveUSB, and then selected the option to *Install Ubuntu* to my hard drive. I allowed the installer to partition it, giving Ubuntu 50GB and leaving Windows 7 with 200GB. However, when I boot, It still boot straight into Windows. The only way to access GRUB is by booting from the LiveUSB, although this can then be removed.

How do I access the GRUB menu without using the USB?

Comment: Please remember to accept/upvote the best answer(s) to your question when possible (tick/check mark on the left). This way, the question is marked as "answered" and future readers can refer to it knowing the solution works. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

What you need to do is run Ubuntu from LiveCD or LiveUSB and install *boot-repair*.
To install *boot-repair*, open up a terminal and type the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

*boot-repair* will automatically launch, if is doesn't, launch it via Dash. 
Make sure to select *recommended repair* to repair and get grub back.

Reboot and grub will be back on boot.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to be of service.

Comment: @Niall, You can accept this as the answer, which may help future visitor

Comment: By the way, thank you @AnwarShah for the edit. Better late than never.

Answer (score 1):

[Duplicate post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152539/how-to-make-grub-stop-appearing-every-time-i-boot/152625#152625)

Open the terminal and run this command:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

ADD comment line (add "#"):

```
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
```

It must look like this (by default)

```
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
```

Update your GRUB with this comand:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot your system and you will see how the system will now stop at the GRUB2 boot screen.

Comment: I never tried this as the first response worked, but thanks anyway for your help :)

Comment: This makes GRUB automatically boot the default operating system (that is, it makes it *not* appear). That doesn't answer this question, because this question is asking how to *make it appear*.

Answer (score 1):

As I've [mentioned here](https://askubuntu.com/a/159528/22949):

> Assuming you installed your Ubuntu system *alongside* Windows (by
>   booting from a CD/DVD or USB flash drive and running the installer),
>   and not *inside* Windows (with the Wubi installer), this problem can
>   almost always be solved easily by reinstalling GRUB2 to the Master
>   Boot Record, using [any of these methods](https://askubuntu.com/a/159528/22949).