# Ubuntu doesn't boot after installation

Tags: installation, boot, grub2

I just installed the latest version of Ubuntu next to my Windows 7 system. After I restarted my computer, it started Windows 7. I looked under Computer if I can start Ubuntu under Windows 7, but it does not show me the partition where I installed Ubuntu with 3 partitions. I restarted again, went to boot menu, but wasn't able to start Ubuntu. What can I do?

Comment: how did you installed? wubi installer?

Comment: Related: [How can I get GRUB to appear after installing Ubuntu with Windows 7 using a LiveUSB?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/158321/how-can-i-get-grub-to-appear-after-installing-ubuntu-with-windows-7-using-a-live)

Answer (score 5):

Since you mentioned you have used three  partition I will assume you want a dual boot not an wubi install.

Boot using a live usb/cd of ubuntu. 
Use `boot-repair` to fix the problem.

After booting with live usb/cd ,Run following command in terminal,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Use `Recomended Repair`

At the end it will give a link , note it down before rebooting. If the above doesn't work just post that url here.

More information can be found here- > https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you installed your Ubuntu system *alongside* Windows (by booting from a CD/DVD or USB flash drive and running the installer), and not *inside* Windows (with the Wubi installer), this problem can almost always be solved easily by reinstalling GRUB2 to the Master Boot Record, using [any of these methods](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Reinstalling_GRUB_2).

Answer (score 0):

If you installed using the [WUBI installer](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide/) then when you restart your machine it should prompt you from the boot windows boot menu. you can choose to boot either your windows install or the Ubuntu. Were you not given this option when you restart he machine?

Comment: no I could not choose between the systems?

Comment: Follow the @web-E answer above that should help you. Thanks