# Installer installed system to USB stick, not main hdd

Tags: installation, usb

Yesterday I installed ubuntu 12.04 to my computer and when I finished I realized that it had installed onto the USB stick. Now I have to boot the computer from USB each time I want to use it. What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: are you sure you installed in your hard disk.if so you just need to repair the grub. http://askubuntu.com/a/159474/35775

Comment: Its obvious that the installation failed and it keeps booting from your USB.Try re-burning the ubuntu .iso to your USB  and give it another try.

Comment: You say that you have installed it to the USB flash drive. Did you use Unetbootin? Or did you boot a liveCD and install it to there?

Comment: I created with Startup Disk Creator in ubuntu. I think I marked the wrong part, of the options that are in the bottom

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Create a USB drive or bootable CD if you have a spare drive or system. Simply follow the instructions at [ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-ubuntu-desktop). See the right side for information specifically on your OS.

Comment: is there any software to make the booteable memory using XP¿

Comment: this should work: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows
It uses Pendrive Linux which you can find here: http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/#button