# Installing GRUB2

Tags: grub2, xubuntu, windows-10

I need to install `grub2` on Ubuntu 16 LTS.

When I try to boot both Windows 10 and Ubuntu, Windows 10 loads fine, But Ubuntu loads once and twice does not. I am afraid to damage the hard disk because i have to press power button to boot again!

Comment: First of all, please read and understand this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: How are you booting Ubuntu even once if there's no grub boot loader?

Comment: Why is your question heading is **Installing Ubuntu** It doesn't look like any question. Look [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sometimes it opens and sometimes it goes dark.  Siraj

Comment: It's not installing Ubuntu  Siraj it's Installing GRUP2

Comment: So you have grub and just need to repair. Go through [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/159469/ubuntu-doesnt-boot-after-installation?noredirect=1&lq=1). Hope it'll help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu doesn't boot after installation](http://askubuntu.com/questions/159469/ubuntu-doesnt-boot-after-installation)