# Grub boot problem

Tags: grub2, windows-10

I have two copies along side each others Windows-10 and Ubuntu-16, suddenly Windows-10 just opens and Ubuntu-16 didn't open, so I tried to use

> EasyBCD Program in Window-10

Then I added three entry to open Ubuntu using *EasyBCD* while using Windows-10.

After booting again it gave me three options about Ubuntu-16

*- Ubuntu
 - Ubuntu 2
 - Ubuntu 3*

But gave me nothing about Windows-10 and the three Ubuntu entries don't open also!

Now I just need to boot Windows-10 because I have a lot of programs on it.

I don't need Ubuntu anymore.

What should I do?

[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i want to remove these entry and open windows-10 again what should i do ?

Comment: You should [edit] your question and remove ambiguities. Also, as I told you before you need to read and understand https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI and not use EasyBCD.

Comment: *suddenly Windows-10 just opens and Ubuntu-16 didn't open*... Please be specific and assertive regarding what works and what doesn't. Your other question is also confusing: https://askubuntu.com/questions/887542/installing-grub2

Comment: After using EasyBCD nothing opens after boot.

Comment: Again, [edit] your question to include any relevant information. Do not just leave it in comments than can be deleted for any number of reasons.

Comment: Also post **exactly** what you did with the software you shouldn't have used: EasyBCD. There lays the problem.

Comment: *I don't need Ubuntu anymore* and itś probably for the better. Now, how was Windows installed, UEFI or Legacy mode? Note: In any modern hardware a factory installed Windows 10 is always in UEFI mode.

Answer (score -1):

I burned a Windows-7 on a USB then used it for repair the system and recover back Windows-10 then restart my device and found that Windows-10 back in

> windows boot manager

Windows-10 worked again but, can anyone tell me how to restore my Grub boot menu of Ubuntu, if nobody knows, I even don't care(It's optional).