# Unable to Boot into Ubuntu after re-installing Windows 7

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot

I installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 7 and everything worked well. But a problem arose where I had to reinstall Windows 7 so I did. But after the install, I am no longer able to boot into Ubuntu, there is no screen that allows any options, it loads directly into Windows 7.

Any solutions to solving this without having to re-install Ubuntu?

When I re-installed Windows 7, I was cautious enough to not install it accidentally on the Ubuntu partition and only install it on the Windows partition.

The Ubuntu partitions and swap area is still there so I believe I haven't lost anything, I'm just unable to boot into Ubuntu.

Comment: You will need to run boot-repair to reinstall grub which is the boot screen that allows you to choose an OS to boot into. Please see the following similar question: [How can I get GRUB to appear after installing Ubuntu with Windows 7 using a LiveUSB?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/158321/how-can-i-get-grub-to-appear-after-installing-ubuntu-with-windows-7-using-a-live/158322#158322)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Answer (score 4):

If you have a Ubuntu Live CD , then start Live session .

In The Live session , open your terminal and type this

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
```

Give a Enter shot

and then type this

```
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

then it will open boot-repair as shown in image there select `Recommended Repair Option` . It will do the job of restoring your GRUB and then give a restart . remove your CD . There you go with your GRUB .

Source :https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair [image]

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to resolve this problem is to boot your computer from a live Ubuntu CD or USB then install and run Boot Repair to reinstall grub and recover access to Ubuntu.
Have a look a the following link for instructions on installing and using boot repair.

[Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)