# Couldn't boot Windows7 after installing 12.04 on a Dell N 5050 laptop

Tags: grub2, windows-7, boot-failure

I installed 12.04(64bit) alongside Windows 7 (64bit) through a USB drive.

Earlier I couldn't load Ubuntu without a USB drive until I ran `sudo grub-install --force /dev/sda2`.

But now I can't load `Windows 7 (loader)(on/dev/sda2)` in GRUB. When I select that, it displays a black screen and then returns to GRUB.

Help me to solve this. I read "Installing GRUB 2" article but I cannot understand what I should do.

Comment: Try installing boot-repair. See [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/158322/74307) on installing boot-repair.

Comment: You were supposed to install GRUB in the MBR (**grub-install /dev/sda**) not in the partition containing Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Boot into Ubuntu, open up a terminal (shortcut `Ctrl+Alt+T`), and type `update-grub` and press `Enter`. You'll need to enter your root password. After it's done, reboot your system.

Comment: I did that but it not work....

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

Boot into Ubuntu and open the terminal(Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard) or look for it in the dash. Once opened, try the following commands:

```
sudo grub-install "(hd0)"
sudo update-grub
```

That should do it. When you run that last command, make sure to see Windows. Take a look at this example. See Windows at the bottom:

[image: Example of what sudo update-grub renders]

If you do not see Windows, then you might have installed your dual boot wrong.

Tell me if it works. Hope this helps you.