# Ubuntu not getting installed

Tags: 12.04, installation, dual-boot, windows-7

I downloaded ubuntu 12.04 lts 64bit version. Laptop already has windows 7 and installed along side windows 7. After installation, it is not showing up in boot menu. Instead it is directly booting to windows 7. Laptop supports 64 bit. I did the same thing in my pc, but it worked fine. Also after installation, in windows 7, the ext4 partition doesn't show up. Please help. Thank You

Comment: Don't worry ext4 wont show up on windows and for boot menu see this http://askubuntu.com/questions/158321/how-can-i-get-grub-to-appear-after-installing-ubuntu-with-windows-7-using-a-live/158322#158322

Answer (score 0):

ext4 partitions will not be shown/mounted under Windows.

Ubuntu can be added to Windows bootloader by using a simple easy-to-use software EasyBCD.

Please follow the instructions provided by EasyBCD creators [here](http://neosmart.net/wiki/easybcd/dual-boot/linux/ubuntu/#Adding_Ubuntu_to_the_Windows_Bootloader).

Steps 5-7 can be omitted if you want to see GRUB for about 10 seconds. This might be useful if you want to boot into a different kernel for Ubuntu.

Download EasyBCD without registering in their website by following this [link](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/OS-Enhancements/EasyBCD.shtml).

> **Disclaimer:** Keep in mind, this will enable windows bootloader by
>   default, not GRUB. If you want to keep GRUB as default bootmanager,
>   follow the tutorial mentioned by @m-tarun.

Comment: @k1chv : Thank you for the answer. But it's not working. I followed the instructions specified in the EasyBCD link you've specified. But its not working. The problem is its only showing windows 7 in the boot menu.

Comment: @sandesh, it is my goto method to install ubuntu or any Linux in my machine alongside windows. Are you sure Ubuntu got installed correctly? 
Redo the steps mentioned in the Neosmart.com guide for one last time. If not reinstall Ubuntu and see what happens.

Comment: @k1chv : Ya, installation went correctly. Re-installed 4 times now. Is it the problem of 64 bit ?

Comment: 64 bit should not give a problem. Check where the EasyBCD is pointing to as boot drive for Ubuntu. It should be to /boot for Ubuntu not to C:\ which is for Windows.

Comment: At first no entry was shown, after installation. I added a new entry and after that, it is showing to C:\. It is not pointing to /boot

Comment: @sandesh, I did install elementary OS (based off Ubuntu 12.04 LTS) this weekend and used EasyBCD to dual boot. The new entry for linux was pointing to C:\ and still linux booted. For linux you should select GRUB2 in the option as Ubuntu 12.04+ uses GRUB 2. Hope this helps.