# How to get rid of Windows

Tags: windows

I think the answer must be very simple, but I still don't know it.
I have installed Ubuntu 12.10 in my Windows 7 laptop.
After installing Ubuntu and started using it I decided to restart my laptop. But when I turned it on again,it still asks me if I want to use Windows 7 or Ubuntu.
How can I get rid of Windows 7 so as to start directly from Ubuntu the next time I turn my computer on?
Thanks!

Comment: Please update your question with more information, like how have you installed Ubuntu(native install or Wubi install?).

Comment: If you installed Ubuntu natively, then you can boot to a Live CD and change the GRUB configuration. If you installed Ubuntu through Wubi, you cannot uninstall Windows but can set Ubuntu to boot using the "Boot" section of `msconfig`.

Comment: the wuestion surely needs more information. Are the system on the same harddrive? How did you do the install?

Comment: I am sorry. I think I installed it trough Wubi. In that case, can't I erase Windows from my laptop?

Comment: If that is the case, what can I do to install Ubuntu again, but this time without Windows?

Answer (score 5):

### How to Install Ubuntu Only

1. Back up everything you want to keep from Windows and Ubuntu on an external drive.
2. Insert the Ubuntu Live CD into your computer.
3. Boot your computer from the Ubuntu Live CD. You may need to look up details on how to change your computer's boot order; this will depend on the exact model of computer you have. Ensure that it's set to boot from CD first.
4. Follow the steps of the Ubuntu installation process. The Live CD should make this easy.
5. Copy everything you want to use from your external drive back onto your Ubuntu installation.

I recommend that you keep both systems available instead of removing Windows altogether. If you want to do that instead, here are the steps involved:

### How to Install Ubuntu And Keep Windows out of the Way

1. Back up everything you want to keep from Windows and Ubuntu on an external drive.
2. Shrink your Windows partition using the Disk Management utility in the Control Panel. Just right click on your drive and find "Shrink Volume...".
3. Insert the Ubuntu Live CD into your computer.
4. Boot your computer from the Ubuntu Live CD. You may need to look up details on how to change your computer's boot order; this will depend on the exact model of computer you have. Ensure that it's set to boot from CD first.
5. Follow the steps of the Ubuntu installation process, ***except*** tell Ubuntu to use the unallocated partition rather than the whole disk.
6. Copy everything you want to use from your external drive back onto your Ubuntu installation.
7. Edit the file `/etc/default/grub` as the root user, and change `#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0` to `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0`. (see [How to make grub stop appearing every time I boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152539/how-to-make-grub-stop-appearing-every-time-i-boot))
8. Change the GRUB boot order, setting Ubuntu as the first option; see [How do I change the GRUB boot order?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100232/how-do-i-change-the-grub-boot-order) but remember you want Ubuntu first, not Windows like the asker requested.
9. Open a terminal and run the command `sudo update-grub`.

### Additional Notes

I previously had difficulty installing Ubuntu in the above manner on drives set up with RAID 0. It may be possible to do so, but I had to remove Windows and disable RAID. If you have similar trouble, look at the following links for assistance.

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FakeRaidHowto
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SoftwareRAID
- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Raid

Answer (score 1):

If you have decided to stick with use Ubuntu only and remove windows from the laptop then the best thing to do is to use backup to backup your home directory (default) somewhere or to ubuntuone (default) and reinstall this time selecting the option to use all disk space.

That is what I would do.  Now, there maybe a way to use gparted to remove and expand partitions and modify the grub entry but I don't know how to do that.  Someone else maybe able to help with this.

Comment: Sorry, but how can I do that?

Comment: I must say I don't know very much how to use Ubuntu

Comment: You would just need to boot from your Ubuntu DVD.  You need to download the DVD from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Answer (score 1):

Since you have done a wubi install, you need first convert your Ubuntu to a regular install and then delete Windows.

Please refer to this [artice](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635/how-to-convert-wubi-install-into-regular-install) to convert your Wubi install to a regular install.

Now, that you have a regular Ubuntu Install, just log into Ubuntu and format the Windows Partition and modify your GRUB.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, it's easy. Format your Windows partition with a freeware called partition wizard then delete the Windows and modify your Grub. Hope this can help you.

Answer (score -2):

You can format the windows partition and edit your grub to delete the windows startup lines. Try to find a grub editing tool on the Ubuntu Software Center :) See it's easy :)

Comment: This answer would leave Tomy's computer in a mess - Tomy just admitted to using Wubi, and Wubi installs Ubuntu directly on Windows. Ubuntu is managed as a Windows application.

Comment: ah yes. i didn't notice he installed it using wubi