# Grub2 is always asking which version to boot

Tags: 12.10, boot, grub2

I recently upgraded from 12.04 to 12.10 after grub crashed and I landed in the rescue prompt. After a new clean install of 12.10 and running `boot-repair` from a liveCD (grub was still somehow damaged and was not properly reinstalled) GRUB2 always asks me when booting if I want to boot the standard Ubuntu, recovery moder etc... Is there a simple way to set Ubuntu normal mode as standard boot so that I only have to go to the boot menu if I want to boot one of the other modes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The default options for grub2 is to use os prober and when more than one os is present offering the option which os to boot. The timeout can be changed to a few seconds so 1st option will automatically boot

Possibly this will [help](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152539/how-to-make-grub-stop-appearing-every-time-i-boot?rq=1)

A graphical grub2 customizer is available:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```