# Unknown partition

Tags: boot, partitioning, hard-drive

I'm kinda new in this and just installed ubuntu 16.04. Before this on the HDD was Windows 10. I put flash drive with Ubuntu and just erased/format whole drive and installed ubuntu.

Now when I switch on this laptop is asking me to choose to start ubuntu or make some memory test.. OS doesn't start right away until I choose something. Is it possible to hide this menu option at boot?

Secondly when I run `fdisk -l` I see something strange that I don't know what exactly mean..

```
Disk /dev/sda: 465,8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xbde941be

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048 960641023 960638976 458,1G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       960643070 976771071  16128002   7,7G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       960643072 976771071  16128000   7,7G 82 Linux swap / Solaris

Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.

Disk /dev/sdb: 14,9 GiB, 16013942784 bytes, 31277232 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk  identifier: 0x65709045

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1        2048 31275007 31272960 14,9G  6 FAT16


Disk /dev/mapper/cryptswap1: 7,7 GiB, 8257011712 bytes, 16126976 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

1. I don't recognize this:

   ```
   Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
   /dev/sdb1        2048 31275007 31272960 14,9G  6 FAT16
   ```

   I don't know why is there since I formatted whole HDD
2. What is this error means?

   ```
     Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
   ```

Comment: sdb is another device, probably a flash drive.

Comment: No, I don't have anything like this. Just one mouse plugged in...

Comment: Maybe an SD card, etc. It is not a problem.

Comment: When I start `GParted` I see only `/dev/sda1`, `/dev/sda2` and `/dev/sda5` which is like sub on `/dev/sda2`

Comment: No, it's brain new laptop and nothing plugged in. `GParted` doesn't show `sdb` at all

Comment: In gparted you need to choose a disk in the upper right-hand corner. There should be sdb.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I see it there now with warning `7.69 GiB of unallocated space within the partition.
To grow the file system to fill the partition, select the partition and choose the menu item:
Partition --> Check.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Is it possible to hide this menu option at boot?" Yes, it is. Check this: [How to make grub stop appearing every time I boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152539/how-to-make-grub-stop-appearing-every-time-i-boot).